# Increase WCF service upload size

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, class, service

Hello I have the following WCF service, that expects a byte[] and a Id

```
  public string SaveImagesToServer(byte[] images, Int64 id)
    {
        try
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream(images);

            var fs = new FileStream(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Images/") + id + "-" + "Testing", FileMode.Create);

            ms.WriteTo(fs);
            ms.Close();
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            return ex.ToString();
        }

        return "Success";
    }
```

As you can see it returns a string (which I hoped for) but instead it returns text/html as shown here in this error I get when calling it

The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the        binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '

I've searched the internet trying to figure out how to change its return type from text/html to type string but with no avail, can someone explain to me how this is done?

Config set up

```
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="uploadfilebinding" closeTimeout="10:01:00"
      maxBufferSize="204857600" maxBufferPoolSize="204857600"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600" openTimeout="10:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:01:00"
      messageEncoding="Mtom" transferMode="StreamedRequest">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="204857600" maxStringContentLength="204857600"
                    maxArrayLength="204857600" maxBytesPerRead="204857600"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="204857600" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: This usually means you are actually having an error calling the service and an HTML page is coming up, frequently this can mean a configuration error in the service. Make sure your service is working.

Comment: @dbugger yeah fixed the error, I now get this The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large. I've modified the question to show my config set up

Comment: @dbugger I can upload small images without a problem

Comment: @ScottAtkinson so ur error is very clear - if this WCF is hosted inside IIS, ensure u can upload files of the correct size:`<system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647"/>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
</system.webServer>`

Comment: Might want to update your question and title.

Comment: I've up dated the title, I know the images uploaded can't be bigger then the file size specified, guess I'll resize the image before uploading to be on the safe size thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

you need to set some parameters both in the client as in the server. Because you need to be able to upload (client), send (client), and receive (server) a big file.

In the WCF Service's Web.config I add this parameters to avoid this kind of problems:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime ... maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
</system.web>
...
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding ... maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
      ...
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

In the Client's Web.config I add this parameters:

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <httpRuntime ... maxRequestLength="40960" />
</system.web>
...
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="41943040" maxBufferSize="41943040" maxBufferPoolSize="41943040">
        <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="41943040" maxStringContentLength="41943040" />
          </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  ...
</system.serviceModel>
```

To avoid attacks with large messages:

- If the service is only reachable from the client, you only need to fix the size of the client.
- If is the service is public you need to fix the size in both of them.

Comment: thanks for the info, I tried it but I get The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large. the image byte is {byte[117067]} which is width:624 height:337 I want to allow the user to upload images in the ratio of width: 1000px and height: 600px